# AngularJS : Nested controllers not working in ng-include

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

As per the [AngularJS article](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) (have a look in nested controller fragment), I'm trying to implement nested controllers with `ng-include`

**index.html**

```
<body id="spaWrapperApp" ng-app="spaWrapperApp">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper" ng-controller="mainController">
            <div class="navigation">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="requestPage('sample3_nestedApps_f1.html')">
                    <span>Page 1</span>
                </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="requestPage('sample3_nestedApps_f2.html')">
                    <span>Page 2</span>
                </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="requestPage('sample3_nestedApps_f3.html')">
                    <span>Page 3</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="content" >
                <div ng-include="currentPage"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.spaWrapperApp = angular.module('spaWrapperApp',[]);

            spaWrapperApp.controller('mainController',['$scope',function($scope){

                $scope.currentPage = "sample3_nestedApps_f1.html";

                console.log($scope);
                $scope.requestPage = function(friendlyURL){
                    console.log(friendlyURL);
                    $scope.currentPage = friendlyURL;
                }
            }]);


        </script>
    </body>
```

**Page1** (code given below)file will injected in `ng-include`

```
<div>Testing page include 1</div>
<hr/>
<br/>
<div ng-controller="FirstController">
    <p>1# {{ name }}</p>
    <div ng-controller="SecondController">
        <p>2# {{ name }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    spaWrapperApp.controller('FirstController',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.name = "FirstController Name";
    }]);
    spaWrapperApp.controller('SecondController',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.name = "SecondController Name";
    }]);
</script>
```

In the whole case the end result will be nested controller injected in `ng-include` area.

The issue is when I run that code that time this error is shown to me.

```
"Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'FirstController' is not a function, got undefined"
```

Any idea what exactly going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Something unexpected going in AngularJS.

If you are using **ng-include** and try to inject pageX in that area and pageX contains some script, in that case pageX script not executed, for that I just write all the angularJS controllers handler in index.html only and it works fine for me.
like

```
    window.spaWrapperApp = angular.module('spaWrapperApp',[]);
    spaWrapperApp.controller('mainController',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.currentPage = "sample3_nestedApps_f1.html";
        $scope.requestPage = function(friendlyURL){
            $scope.currentPage = friendlyURL;
        }
    }]);
    spaWrapperApp.controller('FirstController',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.name = "FirstController Name";
    }]);
    spaWrapperApp.controller('SecondController',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.name = "SecondController Name";
    }]);
```